# Need to bind the object with the textblocks in the window WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am using the MVVM pattern to bind the entrylog with the textblock.

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:WindowsEventsAutoMountViewModel x:Name="xWindowsEventsDetail"/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <TextBlock x:Name="xCategoryTextBox" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="0" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path= xWindowsEventsDetail.Event.Category}"/> 

            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="{x:Static res:RecoveryManagerResources.EventDetailViewLabel_Level}" Name="xlabelLevel" ContentStringFormat="{}{0}:"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="xLevelTextBox" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path= xWindowsEventsDetail.Event.Level}"/>
```

also the other fields

But getting no values in the field

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If WindowsEventsAutoMountViewModel is your class and it is set to the DataContext, then bindings will by default refer to children of that class.

For example if your class declares:

```
public class WindowsEventsAutoMountViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You would bind it as:

```
{Binding Path=Name}
```

So long as it is set to your DataContext.  Basically, remove "xWindowsEventsDetail" from your bindings.

If you wanted to bind to a resource that wasn't your DataContext, you'd set the Source property in the binding to the resource:

```
{Binding Path=Name, Source={StaticResource xWindowsEventsDetail}}
```

DataContext saves you from having to specify the 2nd part.

Answer (score 0):

Your Path is wrong. You should bind to the DataContext directly, not the element.

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:WindowsEventsAutoMountViewModel x:Name="xWindowsEventsDetail"/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <TextBlock x:Name="xCategoryTextBox" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="0" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Event.Category}"/> 

            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="{x:Static res:RecoveryManagerResources.EventDetailViewLabel_Level}" Name="xlabelLevel" ContentStringFormat="{}{0}:"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="xLevelTextBox" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Event.Level}"/>
```

Comment: Tried that also still there is no data displayed